# How to use a Gzip file as a link

Tags: css, gzip

I just Gzipped my css file and now I am not able to understand how to use it as an external css file as it has a .gz at the end instead of .css
Here is the link files.cryoffalcon.com/bloghuts/Compressed/BlogHuts%20COMPRESSED%20CSS.css.gz

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to send a user a compressed css file instead of the whole document, you could have found your answer with a simple Google search.

http://www.fiftyfoureleven.com/weblog/web-development/css/the-definitive-css-gzip-method